# How to correctly implement MVC3 with Razor radio buttons?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, radio-button

When a teacher creates a question he has to supply 3 answers, one of which is correct and the other 2 are wrong.

```
public class AddQuestion
{
    public string QuesBody { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> AnsLst { get; set; }
}
```

And each answer has its body and a bool field indicating if it is the correct one:

```
public class AddQuestion
{
    public string AnswerBody { get; set; }
    public bool Correct { get; set; }
}
```

I try to use a radio button to indicate which answer is the correct one.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.AnsLst[0].AnswerBody)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.AnsLst[0].Correct, false) 
<br />
@Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.AnsLst[1].AnswerBody)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.AnsLst[1].Correct, false)
<br />
@Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.AnsLst[2].AnswerBody)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.AnsLst[2].Correct, false)
```

The problem is that: when I select 2, or even 3, radio buttons, they all stay active. It should be only one is active at a time.
How can I enforce them to keep only one active at a time, and how to retrieve its value???

Comment: this smells like homework

Comment: It is my final graduation project. @Eonasdan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter is the value to summit when the form is posted.  It would be more appropriate to have

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.AnsLst[0])
@Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.SelectedAnswer, 0) 
<br />
@Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.AnsLst[1])
@Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.SelectedAnswer, 1)
<br />
@Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.AnsLst[2])
@Html.RadioButtonFor(c => c.SelectedAnswer, 2)
```

With your Model looking like this

```
public class AddQuestion
{
    public string QuesBody { get; set; }
    public List<string> AnsLst { get; set; }
    public int SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @caderll0. It is bool field, only 0 and 1 are allowed (true or false).

Comment: I've just got the point. Another one suggested me the same trick with some explanation. Thank u very much.